# Close/expand widths on hover/mouseout events

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

it was hard to find a good title so sorry for that...

I've got follow code

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}
.groups {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 70%;
}
.leftColumn {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.group1 {
  width: 85%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.group2 {
  width: 15%;
  background-color: lightyellow
}
.group2:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="leftColumn">Left</div>
  <div class="groups">
    <div class="group1">Group 1</div>
    <div class="group2" ng-click="toggleColumn()">Group 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So in the snippet you can see a wrapper (red border), which contains three columns. The first column (lightgrey one) has a fix width of 30%. Then you can see another wrapper (blue border) which contains two columns (lightblue and lightyellow one). The wrapper (blue border) has also a fix width of 70% to his parent. The the columns within have again two widths of 85% (lightblue) and 15% (lightyellow). Now, I would like to expand/close the lightyellow one, when I click on it. The clue is, when I expand it, the lightblue and yellow blue should have 50% of the wrapper (blue border). When I close the lightyellow it should have again 85% and 15%. This should be dynamicly... I have no idea how to do this...Hope someone can help me..Thanks

**!!! EDIT: MY OWN SOLUTION WITH ANGULARJS/NG-CLASS !!!**

**Descitpion:** I've found a good solution with `angularjs` and it's `ng-class`. I use a `boolean`, which is default false for checking if my column is expanded or not. Than I implemented a new `css` `class` with a width of 50%. I assign this class to my two columns which should have a width of 50% when the column is expanded. So when I expand the column and the boolean is true, they both get the class with 50% width and show correctly. When I close the column again, the class is removed and the groups have their default width's of 85% and 15%. This works fine and it's very simply. Here you go:

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.isExpanded = false;
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}
.groups {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 70%;
}
.leftColumn {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.group1 {
  width: 85%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.group2 {
  width: 15%;
  background-color: lightyellow
}
.group2:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.cExpandedWidth {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div class="leftColumn">Left</div>
  <div class="groups">
    <div class="group1" ng-class="{cExpandedWidth: isExpanded}">Group 1</div>
    <div class="group2" ng-class="{cExpandedWidth: isExpanded}" ng-click="isExpanded = !isExpanded">Group 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you include the click event you're using? (assuming it's just a jquery toggle)

Comment: Hi @Evan look at my edited question I found a nice solution with angularjs. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you want something like this ?

Explanation : on click on `.group2` i add a class `expanded` . on the second click that class will be removed ( [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) ) . same for `.group1` with class `shrink`

then, with CSS , i give the `group2` with class `expanded` a width of `50%` and to  it's sibling `.group1.shrink` reduce the width to `50%`

i also gave some `transitions` so it will work nicer

LET me know if this is what you were looking for

```js
$('.group2').click(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass("expanded")
     $(this).siblings(".group1").toggleClass("shrink")
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}
.groups {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 70%;
}
.leftColumn {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.group1 {
  width: 85%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  transition:0.5s;
}
.group2 {
  width: 15%;
  background-color: lightyellow;
   transition:0.5s;
}
.group2:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.group2.expanded{
  width:50%;
}
.group1.shrink {
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="leftColumn">Left</div>
  <div class="groups">
    <div class="group1">Group 1</div>
    <div class="group2">Group 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi look at my edited question I found a nice solution with angularjs. Cheers.

Comment: By the way: This is also a nice solution without to much code... so I will mark it as correct solution as alternative in case of my own in the edited question... Thanks and cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
 count=0;
 $('.group2').click(function()
 {
  if(count==0)
  {
  $(this).css("width","50%");
  $('.group1').css("width","50%");
  count++;
  }
  else
  {
  $(this).css("width","15%");
  $('.group1').css("width","85%");
  count=0;
  }
 });
 
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}
.groups {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 70%;
}
.leftColumn {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.group1 {
  width: 85%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  transition-duration:1s;
}
.group2 {
  width: 15%;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  transition-duration:1s;
}
.group2:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="leftColumn">Left</div>
  <div class="groups">
    <div class="group1">Group 1</div>
    <div class="group2" ng-click="toggleColumn()">Group 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you asked this code uses jquery and follows the click event.

To show the animation i have included transition duration in group1 and group2 class.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi look at my edited question I found a nice solution with angularjs. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize a `:hover` along with Jquery to change CSS. 
Take a look at this [pen here](http://codepen.io/illdapt/pen/ZppAWb)

JQuery/JS

```
$( ".group2" ).hover(function() {
    $(".group2").css("width", "50%");
    $(".group1").css("width", "50%")
});

$( ".group2" ).mouseleave(function() {
    $(".group2").css("width", "15%");
    $(".group1").css("width", "85%");
});
```

Then on mouse off you can change it back. You will be able to make this animate smoothy as well via the `animate:` property in CSS.

Comment: Hi look at my edited question I found a nice solution with angularjs. Cheers. PS: This works just with hover/mouseleave so it's not really that kind of solution I looked for... It should work with clicking on the column group2..but still thanks..

Comment: Right on, glad you found a solution that works for your application needs!

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, I think this is what you want. Basically **shrink/expand the blue border groups by showing/hiding the `leftColumn` div**. You could later add animations to make slide the divs and improve the user experience.

Check the snippet & let me know if you have any doubts.

```js
$('.group2').click(function(){
  var elem = $('.leftColumn');
  if(elem.is(':visible')) {
    elem.hide();
    $('.groups').css('width', '100%');
    $('.group1').css('width', '50%');
    $('.group2').css('width', '50%');
  } else {
    elem.show();
    $('.groups').css('width', '70%');
    $('.group1').css('width', '85%');
    $('.group2').css('width', '15%');
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}
.groups {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 70%;
}
.leftColumn {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.group1 {
  width: 85%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.group2 {
  width: 15%;
  background-color: lightyellow
}
.group2:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="leftColumn">Left</div>
  <div class="groups">
    <div class="group1">Group 1</div>
    <div class="group2" ng-click="toggleColumn()">Group 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi look at my edited question I found a nice solution with angularjs. Cheers. PS: This doesn't work, the column "left" is no more visible when the column "group2" is expanded... look at your snippet please...

Comment: Yes, I thought that was expected.Glad you fixed it though